# Where does Laravel 5.1 store acl permissions?

Tags: authorization, laravel-5.1, built-in

I'm trying to follow the [documentation on **authorization**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization), but am having some problems grasping how it will work in the end.

Where does it store the **permissions**? And does it work with **roles**?

If it does work with **roles**, how do you apply a role to a **user**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permissions are defined in the code you write in the Policies or in the AuthServiceProvider.

If you want to apply roles by user:

1. Generate the appropriated migrations (e.g: roles, roles_users).
2. Save the roles you want for each user in the database.
3. Define the relationships between the tables.
4. Add/update the permissions (abilities) to use the roles you've defined in the AuthServiceProvider or in Policies.

   #### Example

   ```
   class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
   { 
   //...
       public function boot(GateContract $gate)
       {
           $this->registerPolicies($gate);
           $gate->define('read-very-confident-info', function ($user) {
               return $user->roles->contains(1); // suppose id 1 means user can read very confident info
           });
       }
   //...
   }
   ```